# undefined method `it' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

what is wrong with my code? it says my 'it' is not defined while i was trying to do a test

> shaunstanislaus@Master ~/workspace/sinatra_practice/crud (master) $ rspec app_test.rb
>   /Users/shaunstanislaus/workspace/sinatra_practice/crud/app_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined method`it' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `load'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in`block in load_spec_files'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in `each'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1105:in`load_spec_files'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:84:in`run'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:37:in`invoke'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in`load'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`eval'
>       from /Users/shaunstanislaus/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'

```
it "creates a new bookmark" do
  get "/bookmarks"
  bookmarks = JSON.parse
(last_response.body)
  last_size = bookmarks.size

  post "/bookmarks",
    {:url => "http://www.test.com", :title => "Test"}

  last_response.status.should == 201
  last_response.body.should match(/\/bookmarks\/\d+/)


  get "/bookmarks"
  bookmarks = JSON.parse
(last_response.body)
  expect(bookmarks.size).to eq(last_size + 1)

end
```

Answer (score 6):

Your test should be inside a describe block

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyController do 

  it "creates a new bookmark" do
    ..
  end

  ..
end
```